# How Instagram for Android uses offline_access?

Tags: android, facebook, instagram

Recently Facebook has deprecated 'offline_access'. But, I find that Instagram app for Android still uses that. How could that be possible? I am developing an app that would authenticate the user from mobile and use that permission later to post to user's wall from server (according to user's actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can still pass 'offline_access' part of authentication process and wont gett any specific errors, in any case Facebook will return you a short-lived token.
on the other hand, you can extend the short-lived token into 60days one,

see scenario.4 under https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

example;
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN