# Does facebook access token for app expire?

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

The answers I've found are [No](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) and [Yes](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401563/does-a-facebook-applications-access-token-expire) didn't really get answered (not to mention the links referenced there are somewhat old)
Thanks

Comment: this answer may help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649297/how-instagram-for-android-uses-offline-access/10649804#10649804

Comment: offline_access has been removed, see note at top of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score -1):

Access token does expire. If you get access token using offline_access permission, it will not expire for a longer period of time. Several months in my experience.

Comment: offline_access has been removed, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
The question was how to treat the contradicting sources I've brought.

Comment: The second source I brought states clearly: "App Access Tokens generally do not expire. Once generated, they are valid indefinitely. "